# How to check Capybara AJAX response from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Given a controller that responds with:

```
render json:{ errors: [] }
```

How to test an AJAX call for this response?

```
expect( page.body ).to have_content { errors:[] }.to_json
```

This does not work because it seems to be checking the page before it makes the AJAX call, not the response from the AJAX call.

Is there a way to check the body of the response from an AJAX call?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no easy way to do what you want.

When you test your AJAX features with Capybara, it is normally supposed that your AJAX request does something with your HTML page, and you're expected to check for changes on the page, not for the response of the request.

If you want to check the response directly, you should be able to test it separately by directly sending and checking your AJAX request from your test.

That said, you should be able to use some trick to achieve your initial goals. For example, [you may want to try the `execute_script` method](http://cscarioni.blogspot.ru/2013/10/checking-jquery-ajax-requests-from.html). Honestly though I don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, I thought of having a separate test for AJAX, but then I would have 2 tests for the same thing, which doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: @BSeven, I don't really think there would be anything inelegant here. After all, you're supposed to have unit tests but you're also supposed to have integration tests. And your integration tests normally check same things as your unit tests, don't they?

Answer (score 1):

[Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/validating-json-schemas-with-an-rspec-matcher) has an excellent answer on how to do this:

First, add `json-schema` gem to the Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'json-schema', groups: [:test]
```

Next, we load our custom matchers:

```
# spec/support/api/json_schema_matcher.rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :match_response_schema do |schema|
  match do |response|
    schema_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}/spec/support/api/schemas"
    schema_path = "#{schema_directory}/#{schema}.json"
    JSON::Validator.validate!(schema_path, response.body, strict: true)
  end
end
```

Then we define our schema (`spec/support/api/schema/empty_errors.json`):

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["errors"],
  "properties": {
    "errors": {
      "type": "array",
      "properties": {"items":[],"minItems": 0, "additionalItems": false}
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, we can add the matcher to our tests (TB uses RSpec, adjust accordingly):

```
  expect(response.status).to eq 200
  expect(response).to match_response_schema("empty_errors") # or whatever the bigger schema you define is called
```

Visit the [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) site for the complete technical definition,
but between the thoughtbot site and googling,
you should be able to find out how to customize it to your needs.
Good luck!

Comment: It seems that the issue is not with the JSON, but with Capybara. I think they are using Rack Test.